# ZIO HTTP configuration for max request size

Tags: scala, zio-http

I want to upload a file using ZIO HTTP, but it gives 413 code, the payload is too large.
I can't figure out how to change the configuration of the underlying Netty server to fix the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting with `Server.maxRequestSize`? https://github.com/dream11/zio-http/blob/1b1640f21535da6cf4243d7bc93c439896c517fd/zio-http/src/main/scala/zhttp/service/Server.scala#L69

Comment: @yangzai, yes I have figured it out by looking at the code. Its just not documented anywhere, and reading the source code is normally the last thing I am doing.

Comment: Created this issue here — https://github.com/dream11/zio-http/issues/700

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the source code I have figured it out:

```
private val server =
    Server.port(8090) ++
    Server.maxRequestSize(maxRequestSize) ++
    Server.app(routes)
```